# How to use '@' or '&' in a network share literally

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line

I'm trying to write a shell script for a Mac user that automatically adds the network share to their Finder. The problem is that they named the shares 'A@W' and 'F&E'.

I already tried 'A@W' but nothing seems to work.

This is the command I used to mount the share:

```
open -g "smb://USERNAME:PWD@SERVERNAME/A@W$"
open -g "smb://USERNAME:PWD@SERVERNAME/F&E$"
```

It's not the command I think because the other drives that do not have a special character in them work just fine.

The version is Ventura 13.2.

All help is welcome!

Comment: There are really good reasons to avoid both those characters in directory names - even though they are not technically illegal as directory names, they're both html special characters. See https://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/websites/writing/characters-avoid/

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I know, but I can't do anything about it. It was named that way before I was part of the company.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026168/escape-special-characters-in-mount-command

Comment: @Tetsujin It still hasn't worked for me. Tried everything in the thread.